# Use XSD schema to describe Java Properties generated by 'storeToXML '

Tags: java, xml, xsd, dtd, properties-file

I use [Properties#storeToXML](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#storeToXML-java.io.OutputStream-java.lang.String-) to convert `java.util.Properties` to XML format. However, by default it generates XML with DTD schema for it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE properties SYSTEM "http://java.sun.com/dtd/properties.dtd">
<properties>
    ...
</properties>
```

Is it possible to use XSD schema for it instead? How can I reconfigure it?

Comment: I read the oracle documentation as "it's DTD - period". I did not find any hint that it is possible to switch to XSD. BUT: The docs say, it isn't "used" really. It is just to uniquely name one. So for me the question arises: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: @Fildor I just want to have XSD schema for every XML my application generates for consistency

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the default classes, there seems to be no way of changing a doctype declaration to a XSD-based approach.

But there seems to be a *plugin* way of interventing into the XML storing behavior (at least in Java 8): The method [`Properties.storeToXml`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#storeToXML-java.io.OutputStream-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) internally delegates to a *loaded* `XmlPropertiesProvider` (from package `sun.util.spi`).

This properties provider is either loaded by inspecting the system property "sun.util.spi.XmlPropertiesProvider" or (if not found) by loading it with the [service loader mechanism](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html).

With this approach you can implement a `XmlPropertiesProvider` yourself (it's an abstract class with the methods `load` and `store`) and do those XML parts in your own way.

---

Since at least May, 2016, the [`Properties`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk/file/4676f6c9ebee/jdk/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/Properties.java) class uses `jdk.internal.util.xml.PropertiesDefaultHandler` and the following hard-coded object instantiation to both store and load XML:

```
PropertiesDefaultHandler handler = new PropertiesDefaultHandler();
```

This means the following code will no longer work to set the default handler for XML-based properties:

```
System.setProperty(
    "sun.util.spi.XmlPropertiesProvider",
    XmlPropertiesTransformer.class.getCanonicalName()
);
```

There does not appear to be a way to introduce a different handler because the [`PropertiesDefaultHandler`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk/file/2077a5437d43/src/java.base/share/classes/jdk/internal/util/xml/PropertiesDefaultHandler.java) class does not permit injection of custom handlers.

Comment: And all that just for the cause of "consistency"? Seems a little over the top to me. But kudos for finding the possibility!